# How to find a wall to play squash or racket ball during quarantine?

Tags: united-states, maps, outdoor-games

Is there some kind of wall AI identification system in google maps or some google earth software to find a wall nearest my location to play squash during quarantine?

Excluding hitting garage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such a program certainly could be designed, but there would be liability problems for whoever produced and distributed such a program. It would give users the impression that they have permission to use properties to play squash, while the property owners had not granted that permission.

Probably the best way is to use google or bing maps to find likely properties, then use street view to confirm that they have a suitable wall. Bing Maps has a feature called "birds eye view" which can be useful for seeing things from different angles. And no, it's not AI or automated in any way, unless you program it yourself. I would approach it as though you were going to program such an AI, but then just do the search manually. Start with a list of clearly defined search parameters, such as:

- publicly accessible properties
- buildings that will be unoccupied during quarantine
- not next to a residential building (far enough away that residents will not complain about the noise)
- buildings with a high enough wall to play squash
- no windows in that section of wall or anywhere close enough to be broken by a stray ball
- no nearby anything that could be broken or damaged by playing squash
- free-standing walls
- next to a parking lot or open field rather than a sidewalk or street

etc

Once you have your list of parameters, think of what sort of locations might meet those parameters. Look up nearby ones on google maps, then scout out the property from street view. Some possible building types that come to mind:

- the back side of a strip mall (the front will have plate glass windows but the back usually has very small windows if any)
- school gymnasium (a private or parochial school is likely to be easier to seek permission from than a public school in a large district)
- commercial gym (again, the back side of the building where there aren't any windows)
- free-standing wall around a parking lot (this is difficult to search for; it will rely on your local knowledge to know what type of property in your area might to have one)
- public park (this is a good option because you may not need to ask permission, unless you're playing against the side of a building in the park)

Decide whether to ask permission in advance, or ask forgiveness afterwards. If you're playing against a free-standing wall, you *may* get away without asking permission (although asking permission would still be the safest course). If you're playing against the wall of a building you almost certainly need permission. Many buildings nowadays have security cameras, some of which can be monitored remotely even if the building is unoccupied. And playing squash will make some noise and be rather attention-catching if you are visible from the street or nearby windows. So the odds of "getting away with it" without permission are low. Getting caught could mean just being asked to leave, or it could have more serious consequences such as an encounter with the police, a fine, criminal charges, etc. If you're looking at a commercial property like a strip mall, contact the building manager rather than one of the retailers. For a school try the principal or superintendent.